# Get hashcode by calling Oracle MD5 hash function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g. It has one schema and the schema has DETAILS table.

```
DETAILS table has 10 columns.
```

But my requirement is i want to get a hashcode based on 3 column values by calling **Oracle MD5 hash function**.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any hash function in PL/SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595774/is-there-any-hash-function-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If it is not already done you need to: grant execute on dbms_crypto to

```
SYS.dbms_crypto.hash(SYS.utl_raw.cast_to_raw( column1 || column2 || column3  ), <hashtype>)
--Where hashtype is integer:
-- 1 = MD4
-- 2 = MD5
-- 3 = SHA1
```