# Identify current oracle encryption

Tags: oracle, security, plsql

I currently run applications in *Oracle WebDB* built using PL/SQL. The only access I have to change a user's password for *WebDB* in an *Oracle Enterprise Manager Console* installed on my PC. Our web console and change password page for the users are no longer available.

I am trying to write a new change password page. Is there any way I can find out what encryption type the OEM console uses to update the `sys.user$` table so I can replicate it in my new password change page?

Comment: Not really my area, but surely passwords are hashed rather than encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic sql in your PLSQL to perform the proper

```
'Alter user -user- identified by "password";'
```

statement.

Answer (score 1):

You may not update the `SYS.USER$` view directly. And it is not encryption, it [uses hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595774/is-there-any-hash-function-in-pl-sql).

Use `ALTER USER <username> identified by <user_password>` statements from PL/SQL. Then the password is hashed and stored as you see it in the `SYS.USER$` view. You should make them dynamic, using the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` syntax:

```
DECLARE
  dml_create_user VARCHAR2(256) := ''; 
  s_user_to_create := 'ju' ;
  s_user_password := 'the_passwd' ;
BEGIN
  dml_create_user := 
      'create user '||s_user_to_create
   || 'identified by '||s_user_password
   || ' default tablespace TSR01 '
   || ' temporary tablespace TST01 '
   || '  profile DEFAULT ' ;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dml_create_user  ; 
END;
```